# Porting a 100 Activities app to Fragments without dying

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, porting, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have developed a huge app for a bank. This app gives the user the ability to perform a big bunch of operations through the phone (national & international transfers, securities, stock market values, alerts, deposits, card changes, card activations, checks, etc, etc).

All the app is running Android native code, and each screen is an Activity.

Now we are moving to Fragments... I have the way to go based on these tutorials [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)... I have even optimized their process.

But still, based on their suggestions I will have to create about 100 new Fragment classes;  switch the code I had on per-screen Activities and put it inside those new per-screen Fragment classes; update about 100 layouts; and finally update the way screens trigger new screens (use of FragmentManager instead of Intents).

Maybe not difficult tasks, but tedious.

My question is, anyone know a fast way to port a 100 Activities app to Fragments faster than the one suggested on mentioned tutorials?

Thx

Comment: I don't think there is a quick way. I'm in the same boat and trying to work through porting 1 screen. An automated tool would be nice, but apps are so different in how they do things, I doubt it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the [new capability](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html) of Android Market now its not necessary to re-implement and old application to make it suport both (Fragment and not Fragment). You can upload more than one APKs.

So you can just create a new vanilla version customized for tablets. If your application is too big this will be faster than re-factor the whole application.

Comment: But this approach won't give the pre 3.0 users any fragment love. Using the compatibility library would give users fragments back to 1.6.

Comment: As said above, you can use Fragments on pre 3.0 devices by adding the Compatibility Library to the project. There's no need to worry about keeping up with multiple APKs.